# WordPress Menu with ul: prevent drop down from overflowing menu container

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu, html-lists

maybe one of you knows a solution to this. I want to style my WordPress menu so that only the top level menu entries are shown and sub menus are hidden. On hover, I want to show the sub menu.

So far I got the drop down part working but if there is a menu item at the end of the container, the drop down expands out of sight and causes the whole page to be wider than it should be (especially on mobile).

Here is how the drop down looks on mobile. The yellow background indicated the width of the whole page:

[image: Drop Down Menu on Desktop]

And this is the menu on mobile. As you see, it reaches beyond the end of the page.

[image: Drop Down on Mobile 1]

Well, actually, it makes the whole page wider then it should be.

[image: Drop Down on Mobile 2]

**So the big question is**: Can I somehow make the sub menu (ul) never expand further than the site. The following drawing shows what I would like to be able to achieve if that somehow is possible:

[image]

The html I use is generated by WordPress and looks like this:

```css
/* Display first level as one row */
.et_pb_jt_flexible_menu_nav {
background-color: grey;
}

 .et_pb_jt_flexible_menu_nav > ul {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   position: relative;
   padding: 28px 0 0!important;
   line-height: 1.7em;
 }


/* Hide second level and below and make visible on hover */
.et_pb_jt_flexible_menu_nav > ul > li > ul {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 240px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.et_pb_jt_flexible_menu_nav li:hover>ul {
  visibility: visible;
}



/*Style first level of menu*/
.et_pb_jt_flexible_menu_nav > ul > li {
  line-height: 1em;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Remove padding from submenus bottom */
.et_pb_jt_flexible_menu_nav > ul > li > ul .sub-menu {
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}



/* Remove dots from all menu entries */
.et_pb_jt_flexible_menu_nav ul {
  list-style-type: none !important;
}


/* Add drop down arrow to first level menu with children */
.et_pb_jt_flexible_menu_nav > ul > li.menu-item-has-children>a:first-child:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  font-family: ETmodules;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 800;
  content: "3";
}

.et_pb_jt_flexible_menu_nav > ul > .menu-item-has-children > a {
  padding-right: 8px;
}



/* Make all links use padding to be better touchable and clickable */
.et_pb_jt_flexible_menu_nav li li {
  line-height: 2em;
}

.et_pb_jt_flexible_menu_nav li li a {
  padding: 6px 20px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="et_pb_jt_flexible_menu_nav"><ul id="menu-menu" class=""><li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-home menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-40 current_page_item menu-item-230"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/">Home</a></li>
<li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-231 menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-231"><a>Post (Categories)</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-6 menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-227"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/category/cat1/">Category 1</a>
 <ul class="sub-menu">
  <li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-8 menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-229"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/category/cat1/subcat1/">Subcategory 1</a></li>
  <li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-7 menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-228"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/category/cat1/subcat2/">Subcategory 2</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
 <li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-9 menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-225"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/category/cat2/">Category 2</a></li>
 <li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-1 menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-226"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/category/cat3/">Category 3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-232 menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-232"><a>Post (Länder)</a></li>
<li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-235 menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-235"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/project/">Projects</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-236 menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-236"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/project_category/category-1/">Category 1</a></li>
 <li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-237 menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-237"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/project_category/category-2/">Category 2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-235 menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-235"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/project/">Projects</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-236 menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-236"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/project_category/category-1/">Category 1</a></li>
 <li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-237 menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-237"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/project_category/category-2/">Category 2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-235 menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-235"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/project/">Projects</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-236 menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-236"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/project_category/category-1/">Category 1</a></li>
 <li class="et_pb_menu_page_id-237 menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-237"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/project_category/category-2/">Category 2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></nav>
```

Comment: Can you include the css for your menu please? This is what controls the positioning so it would help to know what it is, so we can suggest appropriate changes to work for your site

Comment: I added a code snippet which shows the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 parts to your question:

**1. Right-align the submenu for the last menu item**

This is easy to achieve using CSS only with the following:

```
.et_pb_jt_flexible_menu_nav > ul > li:last-child > ul.sub-menu {
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
}
```

**2. Only doing this if it would overflow the menu container**

The only way to achieve this with only CSS would be to use media queries and set specific the breakpoints at which the submenu should be right-aligned.

You would need to determine the breakpoint based on the actual width of your menu and point at which it overflows. e.g. if the submenu starts to overflow at 460px but has enough space at 600px:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 460px) and (max-width: 600px){
    .et_pb_jt_flexible_menu_nav > ul > li:last-child > ul.sub-menu {
        left: auto;
        right: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that the last item is not necessary the right-most item. Also the amount of items is not fixed due to the fact that the menu is generated from wordpress and at any time there can be more or less items in the menu. I'm fine with using JavaScript for styling the menu tough. All I want is that the submenu by default is aligned to the start of the parent but in case it would push out to the right, its end should be aligned with the container. I hope that explanation makes sense.